# IBM Bluemix Workload Scheduler job failure alerts

Tags: ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

Would like to know where do we have the option alert and send notification in case of job failure in IBM Bluemix Workload Scheduler service? I was able to successfully configure jobs and dependencies, but want to set up automatic alerting in case of failure. Also is there an option to integrate with chosen monitoring tools for generating alerts/ notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have to open a ticket asking to set an alert via email in case of job failure.
In the ticket, specify the email address to send the alert to.